# MySQL CURRENT_TIMESTAMP Error Parsing DDL for microseconds

Tags: mysql, timestamp, workbench

This is the MySQL table that I want, but focus on `datum_en_tijd`:

```
CREATE TABLE `navigatie` (
    `navigatie_id` bigint(20) UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    PRIMARY KEY (`navigatie_id`),
    `huidige_vraaggroep` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
    `vorige_vraaggroep` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
    `richting` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
    `datum_en_tijd` timestamp(3) NOT NULL,
    `schadegeval_id` bigint(20) UNSIGNED DEFAULT NULL,
    `claim_id` bigint(20) UNSIGNED DEFAULT NULL,
    `gebruiker_id` bigint(20) NOT NULL,
    `soort_gebruiker` varchar(255) NOT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
```

As you can see `TIMESTAMP` is with `(3)` for milliseconds
Whenever I try to *Alter Table...* in MySQL Workbench I get this error:
[image]
When I do View DDL, I get a new tab with this query:

```
delimiter $$

CREATE TABLE `navigatie` (
  `navigatie_id` bigint(20) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `huidige_vraaggroep` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `vorige_vraaggroep` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `richting` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `datum_en_tijd` timestamp(3) NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP(3) ON UPDATE CURRENT_TIMESTAMP(3),
  `schadegeval_id` bigint(20) unsigned DEFAULT NULL,
  `claim_id` bigint(20) unsigned DEFAULT NULL,
  `gebruiker_id` bigint(20) NOT NULL,
  `soort_gebruiker` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`navigatie_id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8$$
```

Note the change on

```
`datum_en_tijd` timestamp(3) NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP(3) ON UPDATE CURRENT_TIMESTAMP(3),
```

Is this a bug or what?
Also note the SYNTAX ERROR on line 8 MySQL WorkBench gives us:
[image]
I'm running **MySQL 5.6.16**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Incompatible change: In very old versions of MySQL (prior to 4.1), the
>   TIMESTAMP data type supported a display width, which was silently
>   ignored beginning with MySQL 4.1. This is deprecated in MySQL 5.1, and
>   removed altogether in MySQL 5.5. These changes in behavior can lead to
>   two problem scenarios when trying to use TIMESTAMP(N) columns with a
>   MySQL 5.5 or later server:
>
> ```
> When importing a dump file (for example, one created using mysqldump) created in a MySQL 5.0 or earlier server into a server from
> ```
>
> a newer release series, a CREATE TABLE or ALTER TABLE statement
>   containing TIMESTAMP(N) causes the import to fail with a syntax error.
>
> ```
> To fix this problem, edit the dump file in a text editor to replace any instances of TIMESTAMP(N) with TIMESTAMP prior to
> ```
>
> importing the file. Be sure to use a plain text editor for this, and
>   not a word processor; otherwise, the result is almost certain to be
>   unusable for importing into the MySQL server.

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/timestamp-initialization.html

So you cant have

```
`datum_en_tijd` timestamp(3)
```

instead you need to use

```
`datum_en_tijd` timestamp
```

or

```
`datum_en_tijd` datetime(3)
```

Comment: But it says since 5.6 that I **can** have `timestamp(n)`, see: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/fractional-seconds.html

Comment: read the last para http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/fractional-seconds.html

Comment: I see, so I can't use `timestamp(n)` since 5.5. Well, so I have to use `TIME(n)` or `DATETIME(n)` for fractions?

Comment: thats correct and note that `ON UPDATE` could only be used with `TIMESTAMP` but not with `Time` or `DATETIME`

Comment: Could you edit your answer that it would be better to use `'datum_en_tijd' datetime(3)`, since that would be my answer? Since I don't want a `DEFAULT` or `ON UPDATE` clause in my initial query.

Answer (score 0):

Yes timestamp does not require this any more, i usually just use it with either DEAFAULT or ON UPDATE CURRENT_TIMESTAMP, you may find either useful.

Answer (score 0):

Some variants to pick from:

`created_at` timestamp(3) NOT NULL DEFAULT '1970-01-01 12:34:56'

`mysql_row_created_at` timestamp(3) NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP(3)

`created_at` timestamp(3) NULL DEFAULT NULL

Each has its own pluses and minuses.

Don't (ever) use datetime, as that has no related timezone, it is mostly just liike a (packed) string.

The MySQL timestamp type is physically stored in UTC (it is a UNIX-epoch delta). It is rendered in the active timezone of the session.